# How to change a value in hidden field from a modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Having a modal with the Terms and Conditions, I need to change the hidden input field value, (name="agree") which is outside the modal, from "no" to "yes" if user accept the terms by clicking the Accept (Acepto) button.
The reason for doing this is that the form can be sent with the acceptance of the Terms and Conditions.
Many Thanks in advance.

This is my code (its not working, the value of the input field "agree" never changes):

```
<form id="formced" ... >
....
<div class="form-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#termsModal">Acepto los Términos y Condiciones </button>
</div>                              
<!-- Terms and conditions modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="termsModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="Términos y Condiciones" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h3 class="modal-title">Términos y Condiciones</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
        <p>TERMINOS Y CONDICIONES ...</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="agreeButton" data-dismiss="modal">Acepto</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="disagreeButton" data-dismiss="modal">No Acepto</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<input type="hidden" name="agree" value="no" />

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    // Update the value of "agree" input when clicking the Agree/Disagree button
    $('#agreeButton, #disagreeButton').on('click', function() {
        var whichButton = $(this).attr('id');
        $('#formced')
            .find('[name="agree"]')
                .val(whichButton === 'agreeButton' ? 'si' : 'no')
                .end()
    });
});
</script>     

<a class="btn btn-primary btn-md" role="button" onClick="return ParaOtrosNavegadores1();">Continuar <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-forward" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function ParaOtrosNavegadores1(){
                    document.formced.submit();
                }
            </script>
</form>
```

Comment: What version of Bootstrap are you using? A possible starting point is to do this through the modal's callback functionality, having an "I Agree" button that closes the modal, and then selects the checkbox on close.

Comment: Switching `$('#formced').find('[name="agree"]')` to `$('body').find('[name="agree"]')` could do it.

Comment: Your code does not show the hidden field. This makes it challenging to verify your javascript.

Comment: Using Bootstrap v3.3.7. I'm tryin to avoid the use of the checkbox after the modal. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, just updated the code with the hidden field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/DTcHh/40696/)**.

Try to target the element directly like :

```
$('input[name="agree"]').val(assignedVal);
```

Code:

```js
function ParaOtrosNavegadores1() {
  document.formced.submit();
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  // Update the value of "agree" input when clicking the Agree/Disagree button
  $('#agreeButton, #disagreeButton').on('click', function() {
    var whichButton = $(this).attr('id');
    var assignedVal = whichButton === 'agreeButton' ? 'si' : 'no';

    $('input[name="agree"]').val(assignedVal);

    console.log('Hidden field value is : ' + $('input[name="agree"]').val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" name="agree" />

<form id="formced">
  <div class="form-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#termsModal">Acepto los Términos y Condiciones </button>
  </div>
  <!-- Terms and conditions modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="termsModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="Términos y Condiciones" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h3 class="modal-title">Términos y Condiciones</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>TERMINOS Y CONDICIONES ...</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="agreeButton" data-dismiss="modal">Acepto</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="disagreeButton" data-dismiss="modal">No Acepto</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-md" role="button" onClick="return ParaOtrosNavegadores1();">Continuar <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-forward" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved. I was relaying on my "js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" but once a linked "ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js" it worked like a charm.